# Button Marquee Stops Once Title Bar Goes (help)

Tags: java, android, button, marquee

When placing this into Manifest.xml

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

It stops the marquee of my button

```
                newBut = new Button(this);  
                newBut.setText("("SOME REAL LONG TEXT SOME REAL LONG TEXT");
                newBut.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                newBut.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
                newBut.setSingleLine();
                newBut.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(50);
                newBut.setSelected(true);
```

Once removed it marquees again..

Any thoughts on why this is and how I can get full screen and marquee buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with Marquee is lost focus. Try below code.

```
newBut = new Button(this);  
newBut.setFocusable(true);
newBut.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
newBut.requestFocus();
newBut.setText("("SOME REAL LONG TEXT SOME REAL LONG TEXT");
newBut.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
newBut.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
newBut.setSingleLine();
newBut.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(50);
newBut.setSelected(true);
```